# Is it possible to make a randomly rotating terrain texture painting brush in Unity?

Tags: unity, textures

I wanted to make a terrain in unity with a dirt texture painted onto the original grass texture to make a path, but when I tried, the dirt (and grass) looked repetitive and full of patterns.

[image]

My question is, is there any way I can make a texture's tiles randomly rotate when being applied or painted onto an object?

Comment: Random rotation is probably not what you want, since textures generally won't tile seamlessly with rotated copies of themselves (or, if they're made to do so, it usually introduces extra repetitive structure into the edges that makes the grid obvious). Could we rephrase your question as "how to hide texture repetition over terrain surfaces"? If so, [Wang TIles](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter12.html) or [blending with a larger-scale grunge map](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/149848/39518) might help.